# 0.00006103515625 GB of RAM. Is .NET MicroFramework part of Windows CE?

Tags: windows, embedded-systems, operating-systems, tablets, arm

The .NET MicroFramework claims to work on 64K RAM and has list of compatible targets vendors. At the same time, same vendors who ship hardware and create Board Support Packages (vendors like Adeneo) keep releasing something named Windows 7 CE BSP for the same hardware targets. Obviously the OS as heavy as WinCE needs more than 64K RAM. So, somehow .NET MicroFramework is relevant to WinCE, but how ?

**Is it part of bigger OS or is it base of it, or are both mutually exclusive ?**

Background:

0.00006103515625 GByte of RAM is same as 64Kbyte of RAM.
I am looking for possiblity to use Microsoft development tools for small target like BeagleBone.

http://www.adeneo-embedded.com/About-Us/News/Release-of-TI-BeagleBone

Nice. Now .. where is a MicroFramework for the same beaglebone ? Is it inside the released pile ?

Comment: Windows CE can be built to run on a small footprint. As the CE Kernel is actually quite small, it is entirely possible to build a CE device with 64K. Of course, if you are thinking CE Mobile devices and .NET frameworks, supporting every device ever manufactured with every protocol stack and UI feature, that is a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows CE should use CompactFramework.

MicroFramework is for low level electronic devices and it is now open source (v4.x).
It interprets MSIL rather than performs JIT compilation.
MicroFramework contains classes for controlling electronic signals, digital in/out, analog in/out, Serial, SPI, I2C, ...